# How to auto submit a form with an textbox onchange value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="col">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <select id="periodname" class="drpdwn" value=" " onchange='myFunction()'>
                <?php foreach($period as $period): ?> 
                    <option><?= $period['period']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width:200px">
        <form action="myprofile.php" method="post" name='periodGet' id='periodGet'>
            <input name='periodText' autocomplete="off" value="Period">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

that is partial of my whole system, im asking how to auto submit a form if an textbox value is change without pressing submit button or enter button thank you

Comment: I am 100% sure, that will provide performance issue while you are doing submit data to back end while doing `onchange()`.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` when with a trigger `onchange` on textbox?

Comment: i dont have any problem with the myFunction javascript, im sorry i did not go into further details i am trying to work around with the <input name="periodText" value="Period" the initial value is Period my drop down is already working and when i select a period it will print inside the inputbox named "periodText" and the value "Period" will change into selected period on dropdown. how can i implement auto submit . thanks to all i appreaciate your help

Comment: You need to be specific. You have two forms. Which one do you want submitted when select changes? And, once select changes, do you want anything else to happen before the form is submitted?

Comment: the second form name periodGet . thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any function to trigger onchange() of the select values. You can simply submit the form when the select value is changed using `this.form.submit()` in `onchange()` function as an example below.

```
<select id="periodname" class="drpdwn" value=" " onchange='this.form.submit()'>
```

```js
$("#textF").keyup(function() {
    console.log($("#textF").val());
    $('#form2').delay(200).submit();
});

$("#textF2").change(function() {
    console.log($("#textF2").val());
    $('#form2').delay(200).submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="path1">
    <select id="periodname" class="drpdwn" value=" " onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option>test1 </option>
        <option>test2 </option>
        <option>test3 </option>
    </select>
</form>




<form action="path2" id="form2">
    <input type="text" id="textF" placeholder="onkeyup()">
    <input type="text" id="textF2" placeholder="onchange()">
</form>
```

Comment: what was the comment for?

Comment: i have no problem on the select form my problem is in the second form thanks for the answer anyways :)

Comment: please check it. updated the code to match second form

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<select id="id" class="drpdwn" value=" " onchange='getCity()'>
```

script

```
function getCity(){

    var state=$('#id').val();// it should contain some value

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>getCity/"+state, //your url and values
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){               
           $.each( result, function( key, value ) {                  
          //what you want to do after posting?
            });  
    }});

 }
```